# Is this bad style?

Tags: c++, syntax, coding-style, constructor, call

I ended up writing a bit of code that goes:

```
Asteroid *a = new Asteroid( asteroidCollection ) ;
```

And it turned out I didn't need the variable `a`, because in the `Asteroid` constructor, the `new Asteroid` ended up adding itself to the `asteroidCollection`.

So I ended up being able to write:

```
new Asteroid( asteroidCollection ) ;
```

Is this bad style, considering I don't even need the return?  Should I make it

```
asteroidCollection->createNew() ;
```

Or

```
asteroidCollection->add( new Asteroid() ) ;
```

?

Comment: Right away, that `new` should at least be a smart pointer if dynamic allocation is needed.

Comment: Well, I'm purposefully avoiding external memory management systems -- that isn't the question anyway - it's about coding style, not about managing the memory.  Is having a loose `new` without the return being caught bad style? That is the question.

Comment: `new Asteroid( asteroidCollection ) ;` leaks memory; why would this be acceptable?

Comment: It does not leak memory if `asteroidCollection` adds the `new Asteroid` to itself

Comment: I'll rephrase -- yes, this is **awful** style. `new` _is_ about memory managment, using it in a context where object ownership is not the primary concern is just going to confuse anyone else who ever reads your code.

Comment: Yes, the code is confusing. asteroidCollection->add(new Asteroid()); is more understandable compared to new Asteroid(asteroidCollection);

Comment: I realized some time later that this is a "backwards factory" style.  If you can't use an `Asteroid` without having it belong to an `AsteroidCollection`, then the factory pattern is a good candidate

Answer (score 8):

I'd say it's bad style because it's confusing when you read the code. The first thing that springs to mind is that you have a memory leak. The confusion evaporates only after looking inside of the constructor and figuring out that the object adds itself to some list to be removed later.

Also think of possible exception scenarios. It would be better to store the allocated object in a smart pointer of some sort and then add it to the collection.

Answer (score 5):

To your question, I would prefer

```
asteroidCollection->add( new Asteroid() ) ;
```

than other two styles.

It's better than the 1st, because`new Asteroid( asteroidCollection ) ;` is no better than something like

```
Foo( barCollection );
```

where Foo is a class, you `new` a Bar object in its constructor and add it to a collection, it's too obscure to know what's happening.

It's also better than the 2nd, because IMO `asteroidCollection` shouldn't care how to **create** an `Asteroid`, it is a collection so do what collections do.

Answer (score 1):

Style questions are always a little subjective.  So in some ways I kinda like answering them.  This is my 2 cents...

Just consider for a moment that you want to be able to create objects that are derived from `Asteroid` and add them to your collection.  If the `add()` method happens to call any functions on `Asteroid` that might be (or use) virtual functions, you open yourself up to the possibility of accessing an object that hasn't been fully constructed yet.

It's confusing, I think, to perform some action like this in a constructor and leave it up to the user to understand what's happening.

I would prefer to just make a simple function.  It doesn't even have to be part of a class...

```
Asteroid *CreateAsteroid( AsteroidCollection *coll )
{
    Asteroid * a = new Asteroid();
    coll->add(a);
    return a;
}
```

If you did want to stay with your constructor approach, you could at least put your original line of code in this function and comment it with a very clear description of what is going on.

Basically, try not to do funny things behind the scenes.  And if that's unavoidable (or in some way desirable), try not to force the coder to understand the weirdness, whether that coder is you or someone else down the line.

At least in this case, it's not really *that* weird.  Things could be worse! =)

Just to take your last two examples...

1. `asteroidCollection->createNew();`
2. `asteroidCollection->add( new Asteroid() );`

I think number 1 is good if you know it's always one type of `Asteroid` being created, and you don't want a user of your class to worry about it.  If the `Asteroid` cannot be shared across collections, it makes sense to do this.  This is similar to the function I suggested, but sort of makes the collection class provide support code that maybe it shouldn't.

Number 2 is useful if you can store derived `Asteroid` types or if you want to do special things to an asteroid before adding it to a collection.  It's the most flexible of all three approaches.

Answer (score 0):

This looks really problematic, who manages the lifetime of the asteroid?

Is it truly shared between the user of the asteroid and the collection, if so you should probably have a shared_ptr to the asteroid so the last person that has it cleans it up.

If it is impossible to create an asteroid without it being put into the asteroid collection then the collection owns the lifetime.

What happens if you create an asteroid on the stack? What happens if I stick that asteroid in a unique_ptr or shared_ptr instead of calling new directly, e.g.:

```
auto asteroid = std::make_shared(asteroidCollection)
```

will it get deleted twice?

If you don't want anyone to do anything with an asteroid then a method on the asteroid collection, createAsteroid or addAsteroid is probably more appropriate. Simply calling the method createNew sounds like you are creating a new AsteroidCollection which I think isn't what you intended.